# libtorrent-rasterbar compiling examples

Tags: c++, boost

I would like to use the libtorrent-rasterbar to devellop some test with torren, but when I have tried to compile the examples which are in package I've gotten this error :

```
   g++ dump_torrent.cpp 
In file included from /usr/local/include/libtorrent/torrent_info.hpp:61:0,
                 from dump_torrent.cpp:40:
/usr/local/include/libtorrent/file_storage.hpp:110:8: error: ‘void libtorrent::file_storage::add_file(const wpath&, libtorrent::size_type, int, time_t, const boost::filesystem3::path&)’ cannot be overloaded
/usr/local/include/libtorrent/file_storage.hpp:106:8: error: with ‘void libtorrent::file_storage::add_file(const boost::filesystem3::path&, libtorrent::size_type, int, time_t, const boost::filesystem3::path&)’
In file included from dump_torrent.cpp:40:0:
/usr/local/include/libtorrent/torrent_info.hpp:195:3: error: ‘libtorrent::torrent_info::torrent_info(const wpath&)’ cannot be overloaded
/usr/local/include/libtorrent/torrent_info.hpp:193:3: error: with ‘libtorrent::torrent_info::torrent_info(const boost::filesystem3::path&)’
/usr/local/include/libtorrent/torrent_info.hpp:204:3: error: ‘libtorrent::torrent_info::torrent_info(const wpath&, boost::system::error_code&)’ cannot be overloaded
/usr/local/include/libtorrent/torrent_info.hpp:202:3: error: with ‘libtorrent::torrent_info::torrent_info(const boost::filesystem3::path&, boost::system::error_code&)’
In file included from /usr/local/include/libtorrent/magnet_uri.hpp:38:0,
                 from dump_torrent.cpp:42:
/usr/local/include/libtorrent/torrent_handle.hpp:585:8: error: ‘void libtorrent::torrent_handle::move_storage(const wpath&) const’ cannot be overloaded
/usr/local/include/libtorrent/torrent_handle.hpp:581:8: error: with ‘void libtorrent::torrent_handle::move_storage(const boost::filesystem3::path&) const’
/usr/local/include/libtorrent/torrent_handle.hpp:586:8: error: ‘void libtorrent::torrent_handle::rename_file(int, const wpath&) const’ cannot be overloaded
/usr/local/include/libtorrent/torrent_handle.hpp:582:8: error: with ‘void libtorrent::torrent_handle::rename_file(int, const boost::filesystem3::path&) const’
```

the version of libraries are : libtorrent-rasterbar-0.15.10 libboost-1.46 
In addition I 'm trying to use it under linux.

If you need something else information I would be glad to give it to you. 
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the solution.

Libtorrent-rasterbar needs boost-filesystem version number 2, but the current version is 3, so  to fix the problem you have to compile it with this flag : 
**-DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=2**

Answer (score 0):

try to use build script.
I also experementing with libtorrent-rasterbar and I can make dump_torrent by next command:

make dump_torrent